# prophet_model.bin error on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I installed `Prophet` library in accordance to the Python API [here](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#python) but when I try to run the same model [here](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#python-api) on the Python API:

```
df =  pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/prophet/main/examples/example_wp_log_peyton_manning.csv')
m = Prophet()
m.fit(df)
```

the following windows open up:

[image: Error Window]

whose rough translation is `C:Users...prophet.model_bin` couldn't be found in the `dynamical library(?`).

After clicking `Tamam` (Okay), the `Runtime Error` raises:

```
RuntimeError: Error during optimization:
```

One of the possible reasons for this error could be that the `prophet_model.bin` file is strangely in the VLC media player format.

[image: prophet_model.bin]

I'm out of options now and I have no idea why I can't run a simple library, and I crave for any advice on how to run `prophet` on my Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem you can apply the following:

Open cmd and type:

```py
where.exe tbb.dll
```

If below command has a result, the most probably is that exist a **global variable** on machine making reference to tbb.dll

To resolve this conflict you have 2 options:

1. Validate the origin of the global variable link to tbb.dll
2. Modify the model.py of cmdstanpy folder on python site-packages on the following lines:

**Original Code**

```
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
try:
do_command(['where.exe', 'tbb.dll'], fd_out=None)
```

**Modified Code**

```
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
try:
do_command(['where.exe', '**OTHERNAMEtbb**.dll'], fd_out=None)
```

Modify the name tbb.dll to other name to **force** use the tbb.dll that exist **inside cmdstanpy folder**:

**site-packages\prophet\stan_model\cmdstan-2.33.1\stan\lib\stan_math\lib**

With this steps, the prophet_model.bin use the tbb library that contains the correct binaries.